# What would cause regression to focus on a few values?

Tags: neural-network, regression, overfitting

[image]

Hi I have a neural network for a regression problem but the results seem to be heavily focused on a few values. I added an image, y axis is predicted values and x axis is real values. What could be causing my problem?

Edit: Shapes of my train set is (5192, 383) and I used 4 dense layers with 512,256,128,64 units with dropout layers in between. I used %15 of the set for validation. I used the epoch with the best validation score. Trained the network for 300 epochs but it does not seem to get better with more.

Comment: Do you ask about steps in prediction?

Comment: @rapaio Yes. It seems like the model is predicting some values a lot

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful to describe a little bit the network? Also some words on the dimensions of the data set?

Comment: @rapaio Thanks, I added some extra info.

Comment: At a simple calculation I see around 172k parameters for 5k observations. There is no wonder you do not progress, the networks si too deep and too large for your problem. I think you overfit like hell. Try first with a much smaller one (at most 2 hidden layer, smaller ones).